# Avoid hit area on link masked with css mask

Tags: css, svg, mask, masking

I have a thousand of text links that are masked by a png image using mask property of css3, I want to remove hit from link that are hidden by png mask,
bellow are two images, the first one is the links without masking, and second is the masked links with png image, my problem is that the hit area is active for all links include hidden links with mask, there are a way to archieve this?

[image]

```
.container {
  -webkit-mask: url(../images/mask.png) top left;
  mask: url(../images/mask.png);
}
```

```css
.tweets {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-mask: url("http://asesoriait.net/images/mask.png") top left;
  mask: url("http://asesoriait.net/images/mask.png") top left;

}
```

```html
<div class="tweets masonry js-masonry hidden" id="tweets"> 
  <a class="txtExtra" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
<a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
<a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
<a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>   
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>      
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>    
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>     
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  
    <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>       
    <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
    <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Without seeing the code (or at least a small demo) it's impossible to offer advice.

Comment: can't you just use border-radius and `overflow:hidden;` on the container to clip the links?

Comment: I minimal demo is required...not a link to an active page that my not be available in the future.

Comment: @web-tiki this is only a simple demo, really the masked image is very irregular not a circle shape

Comment: @xzegga ok I see, please insert a minimal code example to reproduce your issue as Paulie_D said so we can help.

Comment: I don't think you want a `mask` at all...I think you need `clip-path` - [**The difference between clipping and masking**](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css)

Comment: @Paulie_D I has traied with clip-path and work in same way that mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS masking is still an experimental feature. I don't know how to fix your issue and can only provide a work around. A possible way to get your desired result is to use svg with the [`clipPath` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking#Creating_clips) to clip your links.

Example :

```css
svg{
    width:90%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 50">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path d="M50 10 C80 80 80 80 50 50 C 10 10 10 10 50 0z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip)" font-size="20">        
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="0" y="5">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="20" y="5">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="40" y="5">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="60" y="5">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="80" y="5">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="0" y="25">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="20" y="25">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="40" y="25">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="60" y="25">@</text></a>
        <a xlink:href="#"><text x="80" y="25">@</text></a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How I can apply masonry.js over all @ inside svg? if you see the example the @ are placer ramdonly with masonry.js.

Comment: I don't know @xzegga I am not familiar with masonty.js

Comment: I am placing the '@' with masonry in my actual code, masonry its a cascading grid layout library http://masonry.desandro.com/ I want to use you solution but palce '@' randomly with masonry instead with x or y coordinates on each a element.

Comment: @xzegga I know what it is but I am not familiar enough with it to know wheter you can use it in this kind of layout.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to "mask" with `clip-path`, problem is this isn't very well supported at the moment. [More here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

```css
.tweets {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(20.0% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(20.0% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="tweets masonry js-masonry hidden" id="tweets"> <a class="txtExtra" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a> 
  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a> 
  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a> 
  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtSmall tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>  <a class="txtExtra tooltipstered" href="#">@</a>
  <a class="txtBig tooltipstered" href="#">@</a> 

</div>
```